# Change list items that are within a dictionary

Tags: python, django

I have a dictionary like this in my django project which correspond to a config field:

```
{u'active': True,
 u'alert': {u'item_sent': True,
            u'emails': [u'test@test.com', u'test@test.com'],
            u'job': u'500.00',
            u'in_negative': False}}
```

How do I loop through each of the emails above and append `'.fake'` to the end of them? I was going for this - `"test@test.com.fake"`

I was doing this but it didn't change the list items:

```
for p in practice:
    email_count = len(p.config['alert']['emails'])
    if email_count > 0:
        print 'WE HAVE EMAILS'
        i = 0
        while i < email_count:        
            p.config['alert']['emails'][i] += '.fake'
            print p.config['alert']['emails'][i]
            i += 1
        p.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to assign p.config to a variable first before editing it. 'P' represents a practice object.

```
for p in practices:
    config = p.config

    config['alert']['emails'] = [
        '.{0}.fake'.format(x)
        for x in config['alert']['emails']
    ]

    p.config = config

    p.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

I cannot see why your code fails to change the list items, but try this:

```
for p in practice:
    p.config['alert']['emails'] = [e + '.fake' for e in p.config['alert']['emails']]
```